# Iterative Counter Using Arrayformula in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a dataset and want to create a simple counter using an arrayformula that counts the number of occurrences of a person in the table. I want it to give the below result in column `"Counter"`:

```
Name    Counter
John    1
Harry   1 
Peter   1 
Mark    1
John    2
John    2
Harry   2 
Harry   3
```

This is easily achieved using

`=countif($A$2:A2,A2)`

But I need it within an arrayformula if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using google sheets, you can try

```
={"Conter"; Arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,countifs(A2:A, A2:A, row(A2:A), "<="&row(A2:A))))}
```

and see if that works?

[image]